# jQuery only run after the checkbox clicked two times at the first time

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've a checkbox, when it change(*check/uncheck*) it will influence a dropdown.
Here is my checkbox and my dropdown:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <?php
    echo Form::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'form' => $form,
        'attributes' => [
            'isMultiSeat' => [
                'type' => Form::INPUT_CHECKBOX,
                'options' => [
                    'id' => 'is-multi-seat-id'
                ]
            ],
        ]
    ]);
    ?>
</div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <?php
    $base = new BaseController();
    echo Select2::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attribute' => 'seatNumber',
        'data' => $base->selectSeat($tripId),
        'disabled' => false,
        'options' => [
            'value' => $seatNumber,
            'placeholder' => 'Select Seat...',
            'multiple' => true,                
            'id' => 'seat-number-options-id'
        ]
    ]);
    ?>
</div>
```

I set the dropdown changed with **jquery**. Here is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#is-multi-seat-id').click(function () {
    var checkbox = document.getElementById('is-multi-seat-id');
    let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    let param = searchParams.get('id');

    var statusSeatOptions = '';
    if (checkbox.checked) {
        statusSeatOptions = true;
    } else {
        statusSeatOptions = false;
    }        
    document.getElementById('seat-number-options-id').disabled = statusSeatOptions;
    $('#seat-number-options-id').load('create?id=' + param + ' #seat-number-options-id');
});    
});
```

What I need is, the dropdown is set to `disable=false` when the checkbox is change from unchecked to checked. And dropdown is set to `disable=true` when the checkbox is change from checked to unchecked.
My Issue is, if I click the checkbox once at the first time that the page just load, the dropdown disable status not change. But the dropdown status will be change at the second click and so on.

Comment: What do you mean by "will change"? What happens exactly? And how is this related to PHP or yii2 after all?

Comment: I mean, when the checkbox checked, the dropdown will be set disable=true, and when the checkbox unchecked, the dropdown will be set disable=false. Sorry I mean i'm using yii2 for my web app.

Comment: Have you checked whether JS handlers are bound multiple times? And please explain the problem further

Comment: I suggest  to use `change` instead of `click` event. Require to modify your js a bit though

Comment: where is the checkbox that you are referring to in the question , i can't see it in the code provided also try using `.on('click')` rather than `.click()`

Comment: @NicoHaase I've updated my issue, is it explained better?

Comment: I just restart my laptop, and the jquery work well, but after I reload the page the issue start again.

Comment: @InsaneSkull Done, and it's work, thankyou. So far so good.

Comment: the checkbox is the attribute `isMultiSeat`. Yeah, I think it would be better `.on('click')` than `.click()`.